# c# udp check if message reached

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

How can you check if the message has reached the destination, I came up with a solution of mine but as I'm not a pro in this kind of topic I'd like to know some other ways.
My solutions is (client side) to send the packet, if no acknowledgement has been received within timeout time, then send once more, (server side) if the message received is correct send acknowledgement, if not received on the other side then send again.
This is a picture of the diagram of this algorithm,
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GieEx.png).
In short, both sides send the message twice.
any other ideas?

Comment: Why not use TCP which automatically sends ACK'S

Comment: A TCP based communication is able to send a response back verifying a message was delivered.  For your case I would use TCP not UDP

Comment: It'd like to make an API to implement it in different projects such as real time games or streaming, without the need of both TCP and UDP in action but just to use a variable such as WaitForFeedback to let know if there's a time-critical information.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application. But looking at the diagram you attached, you are preferring to TCP communication.

However if you really wanted to use UDP instead of TCP, you have to let go of ACK thing.

Assuming you are continuously streaming images to remote destination. And you do not worry about some frame loss as long as the streaming will be as fast as it will be. You can use UDP with that. Just also consider how reliable the transmission line (physical layer) to predict the outcome.

But if your application is not that time-critical but needs a highest reliability as much as possible, then you can use TCP.

For more detials [visit this]

Below are some comparison with UDP and TCP

The UDP protocol is an extremely simple protocol that allows for the sending of datagrams over IP. UDP is preferable to TCP for the delivery of time-critical data as many of the reliability features of TCP tend to come at the cost of higher latency and delays caused by the unconditional re-sending of data in the event of packet loss.

In contrast to TCP, which presents the programmer with one ordered octet stream per connected peer, UDP provides a packet-based interface with no concept of a connected peer. Datagrams arrive containing a source address1, and programmers are expected to track conceptual peer “connections” manually.

TCP guarantees2 that either a given octet will be delivered to the connected peer, or the connection will be broken and the programmer notified. UDP does not guarantee that any given packet will be delivered, and no notification is provided in the case of lost packets.

TCP guarantees that every octet sent will be received in the order that it was sent. UDP does not guarantee that transmitted packets will be received in any particular order, although the underlying protocols such as IP imply that packets will generally be received in the order transmitted in the absence of routing and/or hardware errors.

TCP places no limits on the size of transmitted data. UDP directly exposes the programmer to several implementation-specific (but also standardized) packet size limits. Creating packets of sizes that exceed these limits increase the chances that packets will either be fragmented or simply dropped. Fragmentation is undesirable because if any of the individual fragments of a datagram are lost, the datagram as a whole is automatically discarded. Working out a safe maximum size for datagrams is not trivial due to various overlapping standards.

Comment: Thanks Leandro, I think I didn't clarify the purpose of this, I've used TCP in the past for many projects and I know for sure that it works great but what I'm trying to do is an api to use on multiple projects especially online games and also streaming applications, as shown in the picture "WaitForFeedback" I want to have a variable to switch from critical to non critical info, I'm looking for another way because I already know that with that variable on true it will involve a lot of memory and thread management.

Comment: @CreţuCosmin ok. So in your case, you wanted not to do checksum when it is not critical. I think it doesn't eat memory but CPU load. However when you change to critical, you enable checksum and this is the time you wanted to send back ACK and check if ACK is received? Actually that should be fine. Also you can try opening two sockets - TCP and UDP. But that will be difficult but challenging. I know that many online games are already using this.

Comment: That's right, TCP itsef is a bit harsh to set up while UDP is not, maybe I'll manage to get the API done and then make it public for everyone, It would be just a matter of send(message,criticalbool);
Anyway I guess there isn't anything that doesn't implement a timeout, shouldn't be other easier ideas.